# javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS2002: failed to get message from MQ queue

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I have a asynchronous JMS receiver coded thus (obvious details missing):

```
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.setExceptionListener(new ExceptionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onException(JMSException ex) {
        logger.info("JMS exception " + ex.getMessage());
    }
});

session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
consumer.setMessageListener(listener);
logger.info("Waiting for a message");
connection.start();
```

Everything starts up nicely, but when a message arrives I get a JMSException which the ExceptionListener picks up. The exception says:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS2002: failed to get message from MQ queue.
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.ConfigEnvironment.newException(ConfigEnvironment.java:374)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQMessageConsumer.getMessage(MQMessageConsumer.java:3047)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQMessageConsumer.receiveAsync(MQMessageConsumer.java:4042)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.SessionAsyncHelper.run(SessionAsyncHelper.java:507)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

The linked exception just says NullPointerException and gives no other details.

I've trawled the web looking for an answer but I am no MQ expert and have got nowhere with this. The middleware people here are not very helpful and getting them to do anything is proving slow and painful. I get the impression it's something to do with queue config but I feel I am clutching at straws.

If anyone has got any suggestions I would be grateful - especially if it is something I can arm myself with and confront middleware :)

I'm using the MQ 7.0.0.2 client jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embarrassingly I have just found that a bit of the 'obvious' code that I skipped above had a finally block in it that closed the connection shortly after it was opened. Not sure why the error message has to be so vague - telling me that the connection was closed would have saved me hours of head scratching.

Thanks for those that took time to read through my problem!

Comment: The null pointer exception answers your question about the error message. If the error occurs in an MQ API call the linked exception will contain the appropriate MQ return code telling you that the API call won't work on a closed connection.  Either the exception didn't occur in an API call, or your code referenced a non-existent linked exception, or there's a bug in the MQ code that failed to initialize the linked exception. If you think it's that last one (and developers *always* do! :-) and can recreate it, open a PMR.  Otherwise, make sure you are accessing the linked exception correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the exception there might have been a MQ reason code given. That could have been really helpful saving your time.

Answer (score 0):

[This support link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IZ44532) on the IBM website seems to be relevant to your issue. Although it mentions the version 6 classes rather than 7, the stack trace is similar enough save for line numbers. Apparently the cause would be attributes appearing in the XML that is used to encapsulate the header info.

Are the client jars you use of the same version as the Websphere MQ server instance? You might need to convince the middleware guys to upgrade to at least 7.0.1.0 and install the latest fix packs, then make sure you use the client jars appropriate for that version. Starting from 7.0.1.0 there've been fixes for the header parsing.